# Get internal SD card location and save images

Tags: android, internal-storage

Like whatsapp, who saves all their images in 'internal SD card' (not internal memory that is only accessible to the app only).

I tried `getExternalFilesDir()` which gives me desired result but that saves data in `android/data/data/package/path`, but I want to save them in a folder in  internal SD card(like whatsapp/images/sent), so that they always stay accessible to app even if the SD card is removed, and also stay in gallery.

Any help from experienced one in this matter would be great.

Comment: I guess the recent Android versions (Kitkat +) restricts it. You can only store file in your internal app folder.

Comment: and that will not be visible to other users?

Comment: you can browse those file but not sure if you can add them to media lib to view it through  Gallery.

Comment: you are confused about the terms you are using. please consider reading the documentation.

Comment: I have read it till what I could understand, hence I came here with my confusion. Please let me know what terms I seem to have jumbled?

Answer (score 0):

You can have internal storage path using `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`. Consider this path as a parent and create your app folder in internal storage like whatsapp

Answer (score 0):

You must get to directory (a [File](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html) object) from SD Card and create your specific folder such as:

```
File sdCardDirectory = new File("/sdcard/Wallpaper/");
sdCardDirectory.mkdirs();
```

Next, create your specific file for image storage:

```
File image = new File(sdCardDirectory, "test.png");
```

Used sdCardDirectory file path to store images on that location.
anso there you put any of the path you want and Id directory path is not available than It create with.

```
sdCardDirectory.mkdirs();
```

So,Use it and you get solution related you want.

Comment: Where should I create this 'directory' so that even if I unmount SD card, my images are there, and these images are also visible in gallery as well.

Comment: Yes, It is visible in Gallery as well, also It store in your internal storage of your device but not in Application Storage memory, It used Media Storage Memory with using "/sdcard/...".